# Google removed my app without any notice. Has this happened to others?

Tags: android, google-play

They did this on the day after Christmas.  The reason:

*Your app has been removed due to a policy violation. This app won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.
Reasons of violation

Issue: Violation of Impersonation policy
We don’t allow apps that use another app or entity’s brand, title, logo, or name in a manner that may result in misleading users. Don’t try to imply an endorsement or relationship with another entity where none exists. Impersonation can occur even if there isn’t an intent to deceive, so please be careful when referencing any brands that do not belong to you. This applies even if that brand doesn’t yet have a presence on Google Play.*

The violation seems to be that I used the word android in the name of the app -- it was called androidDStretch (I also have an iOS app called iDStretch).  The app has been available using this name for over 3 years!!  Why now and why no notice?

Comment: Play Store is ruled by Google bots, if the algorithm says so you can appeal back but it will take some time until real human being responds back. Or you can rename your app and resubmit it, then it will be available again within a week

Comment: I will rename it, but am not sure what will happen to all those who paid for my original app.

Comment: Nothing will happen to your users. Their device will automatically update the app and just change the name

Comment: @JonHarman How long did it take for your app to be live again? My app was removed without notice because I did not submit test login credentials for my app on Play Store Developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Your App removes from the play store because of Copyright, If you use the same of other app type logo, name, mockup, design. Make sure your app play store logo, title, short description, the long description is proper. Also if don't give proper privacy policy URL then also it happen.